# How to iterate through an XDocument, getting complete XML structure, object by object?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an `XmlDocument` which I can traverse with `XmlNode` or convert it to a `XDocument` and traverse it via LINQ.

```
<Dataset>
    <Person>
        <PayrollNumber>1234567</PayrollNumber>
        <Surname>Smith-Rodrigez</Surname>
        <Name>John-Jaime-Winston Junior</Name>
        <Skills>
            <Skill>ICP</Skill>
            <Skill>R</Skill>
        </Skills>
        <HomePhone>08 8888 8888</HomePhone> 
        <MobilePhone>041 888 999</MobilePhone>
        <Email>curly@stooge.com</Email>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <PayrollNumber>12342567</PayrollNumber>
        <Surname>Smith-Rodrigez</Surname>
        <Name>Steve</Name>
        <Skills>
            <Skill>Resus</Skill>
            <Skill>Air</Skill>
        </Skills>
        <HomePhone>08 8888 8888</HomePhone> 
        <MobilePhone>041 888 999</MobilePhone>
        <Email>curly@stooge.com</Email>
    </Person>
</Dataset>
```

### Question 1

I want to convert the Person records/nodes in the XML to a business entity object (POCO).
Therefore I have to iterate through a Person node at a time, and then parse the individual values. This last bit is interesting in itself, but first I have to get the actual Person records. The problem I have is that if I select by individual nodes (using say `XmlList` in `XmlDocoment`).

I end up aggregating all fields by name. I am concerned to do this in case one of the person nodes is incomplete, or even missing and then I won't know which is missing when I pass through and aggregate the fields in to business objects. I will try and validate - see question 2.

I realize this can be done through reflection but I am interested.

I tried iterating through by Person object:

**Option 1:**

```
foreach (XObject o in xDoc.Descendants("Person"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name" + o);
    // [...]
}
```

This gets me 2 person records (correct) each a stringified complete XML doc - formatted as an XML document. Just a subset of the above XML document.

But how to split up the record now into separate nodes or fields - preferably as painless as possible?

**Option 2:**

```
foreach (XElement element in xDoc.Descendants("Person"))
{
    // [...]
}
```

This gets me the XML nodes - values only - for each Person all in one string, e.g.

> 1234567Smith-RodrigezJohn-Jaime-Winston JuniorLevel 5, City Central Tower 2, 121 King William StNorth Adelaide 5000ICPR08 8888 8888041 888 999111111curly@stooge.comE

Again, not much use.

### Question 2

I can validate an `XDocument` quite easily, there are some good examples on MSDN, but I'd like to know how can I flag a wrong record. Ideally, I'd like to be able to filter the good records out to a new `XDocument` on the fly leaving the old ones behind. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're just printing out the elements as strings. You need to write code to convert an `XElement` of `<Person>` into your business object. Admittedly I'd *expect* the full XML to be written out instead - are you sure you're not printing out `XElement.Value` (which concatenates all the descendant text nodes)?

(I'm not sure of the answer to your second question - I suggest you ask it as a separate question here, so that we don't get a mixture of answers in one page.)

Comment: Apologies - yes I am using Xelement.value - well for the second example at least. (It is very late here and I am very tired). The problem is that I don't want to concatenate the descendent values - I need to organise them seperately but I do want to select them all initially so I can easily organise them as a single object. It's then organising them and splitting them up further but I can't enumerate at  this level it seems.

Comment: I am using:
foreach (XElement element in xDoc.Descendants("Person")) 
   {
     Console.WriteLn(element.value);
   }
}

This gives me a concatenated string.

Comment: @MtTumbledown: Yes, it would do. Don't use the Value property - ask for the subelements separately. Accessing the Value property on XElement *will* concatenate the descendant text nodes, which is what it's meant to do.

Comment: Sure - I suppose that there is no fast way of doing it - there is an element of hard graft in asking for each sub element - probably by node id.

I was hoping there would be some 3.5 LINQ support that would fill a structure with the sub elements automatically. Thanks!

Comment: I can do this. It gives me a fairly useful list with each Node description followed by it's value :

IEnumerable<XNode> nodeList = element.DescendantNodes();
                foreach (XNode xn in nodeList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("name:" + xn);
                
                }

Comment: You don't ask for it by node ID, you ask for it by element name. There's XML serialization to do this for you if you really want - but unless you use that, you'll have to do it yourself. LINQ to XML makes it pretty easy, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using XML deserialization?

There are two ways to do that.

- The first one is to **modify the business object `Person` to match the given XML**, by adding appropriate attributes to the `Person` class and its properties. The XML is quite simple, so probably you would just have to change the names if there is no 1:1 match between object properties and XML nodes. For example, you have to specify `[XmlArray("Skills")]` and `[XmlArrayItem("Skill)]` for the `Skills` collection.
- The second one is to **transform the given XML to the one which matches the default serialization** of your `Person` object, then to deserialize.

The second solution will also give you the possibility to filter "bad" records very easily.