# How to import/read data from an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, data-import

How to access an XML file in C#?
How to count the number of nodes in that xml file?
How am i supposed to access each and every node in that xml file?

I have two xml files, one of them is dev.xml which has this code

```
<Devanagri_to_itrans>
  <mapping>
    <character>अ</character>
    <itrans>a</itrans>
  </mapping>
  ...
</Devanagri_to_itrans>
```

the second file is guj.xml (with a very similar structure)

```
<Gujrathi_to_itrans>
  <mapping>
     <character>અ</character>
     <itrans>a</itrans>
  <mapping>
  ...
</Gujrathi_to_itrans>
```

I need to turn this into a two-dimension arraying of the character mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've added more details I can now provide a better answer.
Here is a functional xml parsing and joining console app that demonstrates what it is you're looking for (I think).  To parse xml files rather than xml strings use the `XDocument` Load method rather than the displayed Parse method.  Good luck,

```
            XDocument docA = XDocument.Parse(
@"<Devanagri_to_itrans>
  <mapping>
    <character>अ</character>
    <itrans>a</itrans>
  </mapping>
</Devanagri_to_itrans>");
            XDocument docB = XDocument.Parse(
@"<Gujrathi_to_itrans>
  <mapping>
     <character>અ</character>
     <itrans>a</itrans>
  </mapping>
</Gujrathi_to_itrans>");
            var devanagriKeys = (from d in docA.Descendants("mapping")
                                                  select new {
                                                      Key = d.Descendants("itrans").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                                      Character = d.Descendants("character").FirstOrDefault().Value
                                                  }).ToArray();
            var gujrathiKeys = (from g in docB.Descendants("mapping")
                                                  select new {
                                                      Key = g.Descendants("itrans").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                                      Character = g.Descendants("character").FirstOrDefault().Value
                                                  }).ToArray();
            var crossReference = (from d in devanagriKeys
                                  join g in gujrathiKeys on d.Key equals g.Key
                                  select new {
                                        d.Key,
                                        Devanagri = d.Character,
                                        Gujrathi = g.Character
                                    }).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a key character to translate:");
            string searchKey = Console.ReadLine();
            var translation = crossReference.Where(cr => cr.Key == searchKey).FirstOrDefault();
            if (translation == null) 
                Console.WriteLine("No such key in the cross reference.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} in Devanagri and {2} in Gujrathi", 
                    translation.Key, translation.Devanagri, translation.Gujrathi);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
```

**PER REQUEST FOR SESSION VARIABLE:**

Anonymous types are only intended for use within a method.  To place a list into a Session variable for use elsewhere create a real class of your own that contains the 3 desired properties and change the line of code above very matching this to the below.  (The class name I chose was `CrossReferenceTranslation`.)

```
        Session["CrossReference"] = (from d in devanagriKeys
                              join g in gujrathiKeys on d.Key equals g.Key
                              select new CrossReferenceTranslation() {
                                    d.Key,
                                    Devanagri = d.Character,
                                    Gujrathi = g.Character
                                }).ToList();
```

...then, at some other point in time you can do this to get your session object list into a variable.  Note the assumption that the variable could be null, which would happen whenever a session has timed out...

```
List<CrossReferenceTranslation>() crossReference = Session["CrossReference"] ?? 
   new List<CrossReferenceTranslation>();
```

Comment: thanks fr the code... kindly help me out with 1 more thing plzz... how to store this to list in a session variable??? so dat i can access it in future easily frm othr asp file...                suppose TEMP is an array.
To put array into session: Session["array"]=TEMP;                                      and to retrive the array in another page: ArrayList temp=(System.Collections.ArrayList)Session["array"];

Comment: First, use a List<T> rather than ArrayList.  ArrayList has been inferior since .net 2.0 due to boxing.  I've added code that places the translator into a session variable, but you really should consider a more persistent and scalable solution than Session[].

Answer (score 2):

Try this tutorial on Linq to XML - http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing

This question - [How to iterate through an XDocument, getting complete XML structure, object by object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041991/how-to-iterate-through-an-xdocument-getting-complete-xml-structure-object-by-ob) - also provides some interesting code

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .net 3.5 or later use LINQ to XML by setting a reference to `System.Xml.Linq`.
Here's a simple count of elements in a given xml file to a console app's window:

```
string xml = @"<xml><a/><a/><a/></xml>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine((from a in doc.Descendants("a")
                   select a).Count());
```

Comment: i dont want to display the count,i want to use it further by storing it in a variable how am i supposed to do it? thanks!!

Comment: replace `Console.WriteLine` with `var c =`

Comment: my xml file is in visual studio itself but i dont want the entire code to be stored in an string xml,i want to read the nodes only and store it!! thanks