# c# xml file access

Tags: c#, xml

I have two xml files, one of them is dev.xml which has this code

```
 <mapping>
  <character>अ</character>
  <itrans>a</itrans>
</mapping>
```

the second file is guj.xml

```
  <mapping>
  <character>અ</character>
  <itrans>a</itrans>
  <mapping>
```

i need to access these xml files and store the characters in an two dimensional array in global.asa!! i am using C# visual studio 2008!! thanks!!

I HAVE DONE THINGS SO FAR

```
        sbyte[,] a = new sbyte[100, 100];
        sbyte[,] b = new sbyte[100, 100];
        int count = 0;
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("dev.xml");
        while (!eof)
        {
            if (documentcontent.childnode == "true")
                count = count + 1;
        }

         for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
             for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
             {
                 if(j==0)
                 a[i][j]=documentcontent.childnode.childnode[0].data;
                 else
                     a[i][j]=documentcontent.childnode.childnode[1].data;
             }

         }
```

IS the END OF FILE c ondition correct? i am getting an error!! how to use end of file in c#?

Comment: What have you got so far? What are you stuck on? (SO is not somewhere that'll just write the code for you.)

Comment: duplicate of [c# xml file access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362974/c-xml-file-access). please don't post/ask modified versions of older questions, but *edit* the original question instead.

Comment: i have many characters of this in both the tables,i want to store the data node of dev.xml file and guj.xml in two different two dimensional arrays? eg a[0][0]=अ and a[0][1]=a!! while in the second array i need characters from guj.xml for eg b[0][0]=a and b[0][1]=અ

Comment: @user: this sounds more like you want a `Dictionary<string, string>` ?

Comment: yes those xml files are like dictionaries so i need to store those values in arrays!! so can u tell me the code??

Comment: @user667405 SO is a place to assist with programming concepts/issues/bugs -- not to have code written :) [There are sites in specialize in programmers-for-hire.] I have updated your [previous/duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362974/c-xml-file-access). Feel free to update (your previous question) with more details (e.g. the ones in the comments) as appropriate.

Comment: ok SO i only wanted to know how to store these values?? i am not exactly asking for the entire code!! anyways thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you out:

```
XElement xdoc = XElement.Load("dev.xml");
var myMapping = xdoc.Descendants("mapping")
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Element("character").Value, 
                                  x => x.Element("itrans").Value);
```

This assumes this XML structure for dev.xml (added outer element `mappings` so you can store multiple `mapping` elements:

```
<mappings>
  <mapping>
    <character>अ</character>
    <itrans>a</itrans>
  </mapping>
  <mapping>
    <character>foo</character>
    <itrans>bar</itrans>
  </mapping>
</mappings>
```

You can use it like:

```
string itrans = myMapping["foo"]; //returns bar
```